# Not Showing sqlite data in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have two Tabitems, In first TabItems i have One NavigationViewController. Now When i am running this application it works great but while i am using the sqllite to fetch the data and show in to the tableview cell, it will get crash.
The Crash log is here:

```
    2011-08-18 14:19:08.204 iBountyHunter[201:207] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x4d4e1a0 {metadata=<CFBasicHash 0x4d4d590 [0x1008400]>{type = immutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
    2 : <CFString 0x4d4dc90 [0x1008400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers"} = <CFArray 0x4d4dd60 [0x1008400]>{type = immutable, count = 0, values = ()}
    4 : <CFString 0x4d4dce0 [0x1008400]>{contents = "NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x4d4d7e0 [0x1008400]>{value = +248, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    6 : <CFString 0x4d4dd10 [0x1008400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashes"} = <CFBasicHash 0x4d4ddf0 [0x1008400]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x4d4dd80 [0x1008400]>{contents = "Fugitive"} = <CFData 0x4d4dda0 [0x1008400]>{length = 32, capacity = 32, bytes = 0xe33370b6e7ca3101f91d25951e8bfe01 ... 9e50237bb313d390}
}

    7 : <CFString 0xe248b0 [0x1008400]>{contents = "NSStoreUUID"} = <CFString 0x4d4db00 [0x1008400]>{contents = "E711F65F-3C5A-4889-872B-6541E4B2863A"}
    8 : <CFString 0xe24720 [0x1008400]>{contents = "NSStoreType"} = <CFString 0xe248f0 [0x1008400]>{contents = "SQLite"}
    9 : <CFString 0x4d4d970 [0x1008400]>{contents = "NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion"} = <CFNumber 0x4d1e420 [0x1008400]>{value = +3, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    10 : <CFString 0x4d4dd40 [0x1008400]>{contents = "_NSAutoVacuumLevel"} = <CFString 0x4d4de40 [0x1008400]>{contents = "2"}
}
, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 248;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Fugitive = <e33370b6 e7ca3101 f91d2595 1e8bfe01 3e7fb4de 6ef2a31d 9e50237b b313d390>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "E711F65F-3C5A-4889-872B-6541E4B2863A";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
}
```

Please help me regarding this.
I dont know where the problem is. . . 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the model. Just delete the app from your device / Simulator and try again.

Comment: Let me Check... Thanks for reply

Comment: I have Deleted the Application from the Simulator And then After that i have run the Application. Now new Folder according to the Application are generated. In that folder i have replace my Existing sqlite file with the generated sqlite file. But still it shows the Same error. . .  What can i do now ???

Comment: Please help me if you know the Sollution.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. - You have to provide a sqlite file that matches the object model. Thus, you need to generate a new one. Whenever the object model changes, the so-called "persistent store" also has to be re-generated.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I got it. . . Will try on it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time that you make any data model changes to an iPhone application in development, you need to delete the application from the iPhone simulator or physical device before trying to build the application. When you delete an application on either platform, you delete all of the data associated with it, including the database that uses a now-obsolete data model, which causes Xcode to throw an error.

Comment: I have Deleted the Application from the Simulator And then After that i have run the Application. Now new Folder according to the Application are generated. In that folder i have replace my Existing sqlite file with the generated sqlite file. But still it shows the Same error. . .  What can i do now ???

Comment: Please help me if you know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that you changed data model. The solution for that you need to delete the app from device and re-build the project.

reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";

So you cannot simply change .sqlite database under Decuments folder and re-run the app with CoreData instead you can use .sqlite3 framework for this not coreData.